# React Component onClick do Something depending on prop Type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a react button component...code below:

```
import React from 'react';

const style = {
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    color: '#ffffff',
    padding: '12px',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: '20px'
  }
};

export class Button extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="btn" style={style.button}>Button Text Here</div>

    );
  }
}


//Show Button

<Button />
```

I have a React Button component (Code Above).

What I need to do is to create a property called Type or ButtonType.

Let's suppose we have 2 types "navigation" and "submit".

I want to be able using the **onClick** event change what the button does depending on the button type.

So, if the type is submit it would act like a submit and if its a type navigation it will link to another page.

Can this be done? Is this good practice to do it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
export class Button extends React.Component {

  handleClick() { 
    const { type } = this.props;
    if (type === 'submit') { 
      // submit
    } else if (type === 'navigation') { 
      // navigate
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div 
        className="btn" 
        style={style.button}
        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
      >
       Button Text Here
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

I would however avoid this approach and create two separate buttons that render the main `<Button />` instead and do their logic separately.